# How to channel all traffic on Kali linux through Tor?

Tags: configuration, linux, kali-linux

I am new to Tor and linux in general, but I have installed Kali linux and installed Tor and downloaded Tor bundle, but I realised only when I browse through the Tor bundle browser is when my traffic is being channeled through Tor, excluding any other browser and application. Please advise how can I channel all my network traffic on Kali linux to pass through the Tor network. Note I am newbie to Tor and Kali.
Thanks

Comment: You can use this bash script for transparent proxy trought Tor on Kali Linux: https://github.com/BrainfuckSec/kalitorify

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some site, but describe how this script can be used and what it is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

Download [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/).

Long answer that more properly answers your qustion and use case:

Once Tor is installed (I'll leave that to you; I recommend using the official Tor repos for Debian), add the following to your `torrc`:

```
AutomapHostsOnResolve  1
DNSPort                53530
TransPort              9040
```

If you're using selinux (I'm not familiar with Kali, but I doubt you are), make sure Tor is allowed to bind to 9040:

```
semanage port -a -t tor_port_t -p tcp 9040
```

create a file to contain your iptables rules. For IPv4: `/etc/iptables.firewall.rules` and for IPv6: `/etc/ip6tables.firewall.rules`.

Now edit the IPv4 file and add something like the following (make sure to grep for TODO items and follow the instructions):

```
# Ues the nat table to redirect some traffic to Tor

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Don't allow Tor traffic to get stuck in a redirect loop...
# TODO: Is `tor' your actual Tor user? It might be `debian-tor' or `toranon' or something else.
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tor -j RETURN

# Redirect DNS lookups to Tor.
# TODO: Set this to your Tor DNSPort if it's not 53530.
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53530

# Do not redirect private networks or loopback.
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN

# Redirect HS connections to the TransPort.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.192.0.0/10 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040

# Redirect all TCP traffic to Tor's TransPort.
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040

COMMIT

# Only accept anonymized network traffic in the filter table.

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LAN - [0:0]

# Allow loopback
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow connections that are already established.
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Reject incoming connections.
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

# Accept network traffic for the Tor service itself.
# TODO: Tor user?
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tor -j ACCEPT

# Accept DNS requests to the Tor DNSPort.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53530 -j ACCEPT

# Accept outgoing traffic to the local Tor TransPort.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9040 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Accept outgoing traffic to the local Tor SOCKSPorts.
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9150 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Accept connections on private networks.
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j LAN
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j LAN
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j LAN
-A LAN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LAN -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LAN -j ACCEPT

# Reject all other outgoing traffic.
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

COMMIT
```

For the IPv6 file, you can do something similar with `ip6tables`, or just drop all IPv6 traffic.

Now set these rules to be loaded on startup by creating the file `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/firewall` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
/sbin/ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables.firewall.rules
```

Restart Tor if needed, and load your new firewall rules manually by executing the previous commands.

Note that I haven't tested all of these rules (they were compiled from several places online), and there are likely to be leaks in ways that I'm not thinking of. Suggestions and improvements welcome. There may also be an easier way to set rules on your distribution; I'm not familiar with Kali beyond basic Debian administration.

Also note that you should NOT rely on this where perfect anonymity is a must. You're also going to have to think about the kinds of traffic you generate, and tweak your browsing habbits. The usual disclaimers apply.

### Further reading

- [How does Tor transparent proxying work?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/how-does-tor-transparent-proxying-work)
- [How to force all network traffic through Tor on Fedora](https://jamielinux.com/articles/2013/08/how-to-force-all-network-traffic-through-tor-on-fedora/) (borrowed a lot of his ideas here to patch holes in my initial pass at the firewall)
- [Tor documentation on the subject](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy) with workarounds for several leaks (not included here)

Comment: The issue here in reference to the second option which I have much interest in is that underground apps will bypass this configuration and there are apps that revealed your MAC ID before establishing a connection, after then they keep on anonymously communicating via tor. How can this be fixed? Only MAC spoofing? Isolated connection is to use whonix, can it be achieved without whonix?

Comment: MAC spoofing is definitely something you should consider (I generally do it wheather I'm using Tor or no). The simple answer, however, is that completely anonymizing an OS is a major undertaking that requires a lot more than just routing traffic through Tor: this is why Tails is a good idea, most of the heavy lifting has been done for you. Of course, you're still going to have to adjust your browsing habbits to match too. These aren't really on-topic for this question though.

Answer (score 3):

note that redirect your entire traffic through the Tor network isn't a good idea when you have to upgrade your packages or do things that require a lot of bandwidth. Anyway:

1) Install Tor (if you didn't already):

> sudo apt-get install tor -y

2) Start Tor from the terminal:

> user@notebook:~$ tor

For security reasons you should run Tor without root privileges, so you can create a separate user just for Tor:

> sudo adduser tor --uid 3000

The ID of the "Tor user" should be the lower of the other users to minimize the security risks. After adding the "Tor user" you should create a Tor directory of Tor's user home:

> cd /home/tor
>
> mkdir .tor

That you have to change the current user:

> su tor

And finally you can run Tor.
Note that Tor opens a socks proxy on port 9050 by default, even if you don't
configure one so what you have to do is to set the proxy to:

> socks5://127.0.0.1:9050

And so go to system settings --> network --> proxy and here you are...

I suggest you to don't use Tor when you have to upgrade some packages or when you download big size data... even when you watch a video on youtube or other sites... this isn't a good idea either for you (because Tor's network is slow) or for the Tor network.

Comment: > The ID of the "tor user" should be the lower of the other users to minimize the security risks.

This doesn't make sense to me; am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe you could include a bit about routing traffic through Tor with the system proxy config on Kali? (Presumably this is a Gnome thing? I have no idea what Kali uses by default)

Comment: I don't think that is only a Gnome thing, because I can do the same with Ubuntu (Unity) so I think that is a general setting for all the distros..

Comment: It's definitely not a general setting; it actually has nothing to do with the distro at all... it's part of the desktop environment (Unity is a graphical shell on top of the Gnome Desktop Environment which replaces the default gnome graphical shell, so things like settings and core apps will be the same). Disclaimer: I don't use either, so I know next to nothing about them.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible, but you MUST use a separate box for it. I'm using Raspberry Pi 2 for this task, it performs pretty well. On your box you're not using anything unusual, and on the routing box you're using IPTables + TransPort Tor option. I'll complete my full article about this this week, but the brief config is :

`RunAsDaemon 1
PidFile /var/run/tor
FastFirstHop 0
AllowSingleHopCircuits 0
EnforceDistinctSubnets 1
UseEntryGuards 1
DisableAllSwap 1
AvoidDiskWrites 1
NumCPUS 2
ConnLimit 8192
DataDirectory /usr/tor/data
GeoIPFile /usr/tor/share/tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File /usr/tor/share/tor/geoip6
Log notice stdout
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1
SocksPort 9050
LongLivedPorts 21,22,80,443,465,554,636,706,873,993,995,1863,2401,3690,4155,5050,5190,5222,5223,5269,5298,6523,6666,6667,6668,6669,6697,6881,6882,6883,6884,6885,6886,6887,6888,6889,7000,8000,8010,8300,8554
ClientOnly 0
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 127.0.0.1
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 127.0.0.2
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
DynamicDHGroups 1
User tor`

that was torrc, and in IPTables you're forwarding all the TCP traffic from your internal NIC to that TransPort. Do you need further help?

Comment: Can you give an example of the iptables lines to forward traffic?

Comment: @jamescampbell what exactly do you want to route through Tor? Everything - or something specific? `

Comment: if I wanted to use it as a web proxy from another device. So forward at least port 80 traffic, thanks!

Comment: @jamescampbell if you want just port 80 - use polipo [GitHub Sources](https://github.com/jech/polipo) and [polipo site](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) - it's a way more tuneable for http+https tunneling. Per-port tunneling - In My Humble Opinion - is useless, unless it's proxified by the protocol's tuned proxy. If you need a traffic routing - take a look at my in-development rc.local for Raspberry Pi 2 wireless router protype [secure wireless router](https://github.com/netsafe/linux-builder/blob/master/rpi2-rc.local)

Comment: nice thanks a lot. I was thinking polipo might do the trick. I haven't gotten past using privoxy with Tor / i2p / freenet rules setup in it so I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: @jamescampbell I'm glad to help you! Feel free to ask questions if you will need further help! And a note from my personal experience about privoxy - avoid this glitchware =) When you will make your choice between Polipo and Iptables keep in mind one thing : if you need HTTP+HTTPS - and ONLY them - use polipo, it will prevent ALOT of data leaks due to the simple but pleasant fact : everything that will try to leak your data and/or try to avoid the proxy you've built will be hitting a wall, if it's JUST a proxy and NO routing/forwarding/transproxying. It's SAFE =)